# Is there a way to make form fields and buttons fonts and heights responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a site which has to be compatible with many kind of devices, so I've chosen to use Bootstrap. My problem is that while I have a nice responsive grid layout, I don't see an out-of-the-box solution for making other visual parts of my site responsive. I mean for example font sizes, form field sizes, button sizes, etc.

What I want for example is to have normal button sizes for desktop, and large button sizes (.btn-lg class) for mobile. Similarly with form inputs. Is there a nice, global level solution for this way of responsiveness?

Thank for the answers.

EDIT: I would like to reuse the existing bootstrap classes as much as possible, with minimal added media-query or other code. I'm looking for something like "conditional classes" on elements based on resolution, like the following: if there is "sm" or smaller screen, add "btn-lg" to "btn"-s. If there is "md" or bigger, don't add anything, just use pure "btn". And something similar with form inputs.

Font-sizes and paddings are more simple with simple media-queries of course. My problems are mostly with form fields and buttons, just as I note in the corrected title.

I would like to avoid copying and duplicating more complex (like buttons and form fields) Bootstrap CSS code into my css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are responsive to some extent. To add this level of responsiveness you must write your own media queries.

It's very easy. It's even easier if you are using SASS or Less.

See starting at line 260 in [the variables file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L261). Here's an excerpt.

```
@screen-xs:                  480px;
@screen-xs-min:              @screen-xs;
@screen-phone:               @screen-xs-min;
```

A phone example:

```
@media (max-width: $screen-xs) {
  // Change h1 size
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  // Change .btn font size.
  .btn {
    font-size: 10px;
   }
}
```

If you are not using Sass or Less, just swap the variable `$screen-xs` with the value that you want--480px, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try this tomorrow and give some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

use % rather than px.

Or use media queries within your css